# Understanding equation (5.69) in J.J. Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics 3rd edition

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am currently working on J.J. Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics 3rd edition textbook, specifically in the section 5.1 Time-Independent Perturbation Theory Nondegenerate Case.
I am having trouble understanding equation (5.69) in 5.1.5.

$$
\sum_{k \neq 0} \left| \left<k^{(0)} \left| z \right| 1,0,0 \right> \right|^2
= \sum_{all \thinspace  k} \left| \left< k^{(0)} | z | 1,0,0 \right> \right| ^2
= \left< 1,0,0 | z^2 | 1,0,0 \right>
$$

Specifically, I am confused about the following points:

- In the first step, why is the summation of $k \neq 0$ changed to $all \thinspace k$ ?
- How is the completeness relation used in the last step of the equation?

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on this equation.

[Updated]

This example provided in this section is a hydrogen atom with one valence electron outside the closed shell that is subjected to a uniform electric field in the positive z-direction.

k is the collective index that stands for $(n, l, m)$.
$| 0^{(0)} \rangle $ is denoted in the $(n, l, m)$ notation by $(1, 0, 0)$.

Comment: You might want to include more context for those who might not necessarily have this book on what these symbols are and what these states represent.

Comment: I have now included more context and information on the symbols and states used in the equation. Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For your first question we need more information. But I suspect that something like $\vert\langle k^{(0)} = 0 \vert z \vert 1,0,0 \rangle \vert^2 = 0$ holds such that you can just add it to the sum;
- As for your second question, assuming the $\vert k^{(0)} \rangle$ form a basis, then just writing it out leads to
  \begin{equation}
   \sum_k \vert\langle k^{(0)} \vert z \vert 1,0,0 \rangle \vert^2 = \sum_k \langle 1,0,0 \vert z \vert k^{(0)} \rangle \langle k^{(0)} \vert z \vert 1,0,0 \rangle = \langle 1,0,0 \vert z^2 \vert 1,0,0 \rangle
  \end{equation}
  Where you see the completeness relation appearing in the first equality.